# mount cifs permission denied

Tags: mount, root, cifs, permissions

Hi I have tried to mount with three ways for all of them I got the same error.

1)

```
sudo chmod 777 /estore
sudo mount –t cifs -o user=domain/username%MYPASSWORD,noserverino //domain /estore
```

2)

```
sudo chmod 777 /estore
sudo mount –t cifs -o user=domain/username%MYPASSWORD,noserverino -rw //domain /estore
```

3)

```
sudo chmod 777 /estore
sudo mount –t cifs -o user=domain/username%MYPASSWORD,noserverino,umask=777 //domain /estore
```

Now what I am doing is just trying to create a folder such as `mkdir /estore/asd` and I am getting permission denied error. However when I do `sudo mkdir /estore/asd` then it creates a new folder. Even though I have done `chmod 777 /estore`, I am still getting this error. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

chmod -R 777 /estore would give full permissions to parent and all recursive folders.

For mounting issue, you should also check permissions for directory on source server.

Comment: still i am getting permission denied issue. There's nothing wrong with the server as i can do anything with sudo

Comment: What server are you running? Windows 10, SMB?